# Updating associated parent without causing infinite callback loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have three models: Discount, Flag and Flagging.

```
# Discount.rb
has_many :flaggings, :uniq
has_many :flags, through: :flaggings,
         before_add: :update_flags,
         before_remove: :update_flags

before_validation :unpublish_when_ended, if: :ended_changed?

def update_flags(flag)
  flag.discounts_count = flag.discounts.count
  self.published = self.flags.include?(Flag.published)
end

def unpublish_when_ended
  if self.ended?
    self.flags.delete(Flag.published)
  end
end
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to add a published flag to a discount (`discount << Flag.published`), and that will update the `published` column of discount to true. There is also a callback so when discount has ended the published flag will be removed.

However with the above code the published column is not saved.

I can't call `discount.save` in the `update_flags` callback, because a stack overflow / infinite callback loops will occur when `unpublish_when_ended` callback keeps on calling itself.

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!